# Why am I seeing entries in journalctl like "sshd[144488]: fatal: Timeout before authentication for 51.89.14.103 port 42396"?

Tags: syslog, sshd

I'm seeing a few entries like this every day in the output of journalctl. The IP address and the port number changes.

I am trying to debug the occasional crash of this Ubuntu machine and have started following journalctl, I was not expecting to see entries like this.

Comment: Someone with the IP 51.89.14.103 was trying to access using ssh but he/she did not finish the authentication before the timeout. Unless it's a DoS attack, the crashes are probably unrelated. And Fatal merely indicates that the ssh connection failed.